# Which C++ versions are supported by specific Visual Studio versions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Which Visual Studio Version support C++11, C++14 or C++17?

I assume, that some version do support not all functions, but the question is aimed at the core functions.

Are there any differences between the Community Versions concerning the supported C++ version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I find that [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) should answer your question.

As for the Community Version, it supports the same C++ version as the other versions. The difference is in the tool provided(profiler, static analysis, etc.).

Comment: You'll want this page as well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you suggest I remove my answer and put it as a comment instead? I have read the link you provided and I understand my mistake. Although due to the nature of the question, it would ba rather long answer wouldn't it?

Comment: Are you guys really suggesting he type out 6 pages worth of tables?!

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I'm suggesting something be done.  If that link were to go away then the answer contains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a bit of a tricky question. For GCC/libstdc++ and Clang/libc++ the answer is usually pretty clear along the lines of: “Full support for all C++XX language and library features starting from version X.Y”.

But MSVC even in the very latest version does not have full support for C++11. On the other hand it already has a lot of the features from C++14 and even the upcoming C++17. So the question you’ll have to answer is: *Which features do I want/need and from which version are they available?* The links from the other question and its comments are a good starting point for this:

- [Support For C++11/14/17 Features (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)
- [Visual C++ Team Blog: C++17 Features In Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/). There may be new versions of this blog post for newer VS versions as they are released. Look for [posts by Stephan T. Lavavej](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=stephan%20t.%20lavavej&beta=0&rn=Visual+C%2B%2B+Team+Blog&rq=site:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog&ac=3) to find the latest one. He is the maintainer of Microsoft’s standard library implementation.

As a rule of thumb I recommend you always go with the very latest version you can get your hands on. And if that’s not possible you probably don’t want to go older than VS 2015.

Microsoft constantly closes more and more of those older holes in their implementation. So probably and hopefully by C++20 or C++23 the situation will be similar to Clang or GCC.